# Does a slack bot listening for specific message events get invoked every time a new message is posted? Has anyone encountered problems with this?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Just curious to know how others handle this from a security perspective. In a workaround related to Microsoft Power Automate, I'm using events and bolt-python to listen for a key word that will trigger an action to my bot endpoint. The issue is, as I'm building and testing this, every message posted is triggering an unhandled request and invoking my bot.of course the logic I want will execute fine when the key word is triggered but the amount of unnecessary triggers with the messages is concerning.